# Unity UI Button State Transition through code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am willing to change buttons state (pressed, deactive, highlight) through code in C#. Like on certain action I want to switch the button state to deactive. How can i do this?

I tried to set button state but i didn't find any property accept spriteState.
I tried to set disabled state through this

```
        public Sprite activeBtnState;
        public Sprite deactiveBtnState;//button disable sprite that will be applied
        public Button BtnToChange;//button whoes state require to change

        public void NavigationTask() {
         if (isBtnActive)
                    {
                        BtnToChange.interactable = false;
                        BtnToChange.spriteState.disabledSprite = deactiveBtnState;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        BtnToChange.interactable = true;
                    }
              }
```

> Error 11  Cannot modify the return value of
>   'UnityEngine.UI.Selectable.spriteState' because it is not a variable

Additionally is there any **built-in functionality(function)** available that automatically change my button state and i dont write code to manage sprites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Button.interactable` to change `Button` states.

Disable:

```
BtnToChange.interactable = false;
```

Enable:

```
BtnToChange.interactable = true;
```

Comment: You might be able to use BtnToChange.isInterractable () = false to disable to button

Comment: This works if you want to change the interactability of the button, but doesn't allow you to change the state from normal to highlighted for instance.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable-spriteState.html) :

```
//Creates an instance of a sprite state (This includes the highlighted, pressed and disabled sprite.
// Assign the sprites in edit mode
public SpriteState sprState = new SpriteState(); // <- IMPORTANT DECLARATION
public Button BtnToChange;

// You can even change the transition type
public Selectable.Transition transition ;

 public void NavigationTask()
 {
     if (isBtnActive)
     {
         BtnToChange.interactable = false;
         BtnToChange.spriteState = sprState ; // <- IMPORTANT LINE
     }
     else
     {
         BtnToChange.interactable = true;
     }
 }
```

Comment: You added a comment saying _"Hey Mabecr did you understand the question?? I am willing to change the state of buttons, i dont want to active deactive it"_. I guessed he/she didn't answer your question. If the solution of Mabecr fits your needs, please, mark it as the correct answer then.

Comment: The answer is not the same, take a look closer to it `BtnToChange.spriteState = sprState`. I've just reused your code so that you just have to copy-paste it into your file.